# Multiplying elements of one dataframe by values from another dependent upon column in R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have two dataframes. One contains subject IDs in the first column and then 25 columns of variables. The second contains a first column of value names (e.g. mean, std etc) and then 25 columns with the same variable names as in df1. I would like to multiply each element in df1 by a corresponding value (called OIS) in df2, but this value should be dependent upon the column name. It's a bit complicated to explain so please see code i have so far below for further explanation:

```
OIS <- which(df2[,1] == "OIS")
#i tried to index into the OIS column in df2

# Loop over each nutrient column in df1

for (i in 2:ncol(df1)) {
  df1[,i] <- df1[,i] * df2[OIS, i]
  
}
```

then i tried to loop over each element of df1 using the corresponding OIS value in df2

However, I just get a matrix filled with NAs returned and / or the following: Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: please provide examples

Comment: You say two dataframes but then refer to a matrix. Which class are they? If matrices, then of course if `df2[,1]` is a string then all of `df2` will be strings, for which multiplication `*` has no meaning (and that error is returned, see `"A" * 1`).